# Argument of ? has an extra }

Tags: overleaf

I copied some code from a friend of mine (i'm an absolute latex noob) and while it compiles on her project (on Overleaf) it won't compile on mine (which is the exact same project) with error "Argument of ? has an extra }" where ? is an unkown character.
Then it gives two "Runaway Argument?" errors, everything on the last line of the code below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside, table, xcdraw]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\geometry{a4paper,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,left=5cm,right=2cm,
heightrounded,bindingoffset=5mm}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[framed,numbered,autolinebreaks,useliterate]{mcode}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{ {Immagini/} }
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\newcommand\myemptypage{
    \null
    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \addtocounter{page}{-1}
    \newpage
   }
\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{subfiles}
\begin{document}

\includepdf[]{Template_IngAuto.pdf}
```

I think it might be some weird Overleaf problem since i tried to use another platform to compile it (Papeeria) and although it works, it doesn't show the pdf and if i remove that it gives me some weird problems.

Comment: I did not get any error, using your code (and [replacing the image by a dummy image](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)). However: Don't use `\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}`. Option `utf8x` is broken for a long time.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Note that Overleaf is only a TeX editor that uses the standard TeX Live distribution under the hood. So, if you got an error on Overleaf, it is very likely that you used different settings that you colleague. Do you use the same compiler? It could be the case that this piece of code is only compilable with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and not with the default PDFLaTeX. Note that the `mcode` package is not part of a regular TeX Live distribution and hence probably not available on Overleaf (so you need to upload the relevant .sty file to your working directory).

Comment: If you think the issue could "be some weird Overleaf problem", you may want to contact the Overleaf Helpdesk directly and ask them for help.

Comment: @cabohah utf8x has been repaired, but yes, it is a good idea to remove it (the whole inputenc line). It is not needed and on overleaf utf8x still can error.

Comment: It was the option utf8x .... i can't believe i lost so much time because of this. Thank you everyone.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Ah, one more package emergency-maintained by David. Thanks to the information and many thanks to David!

Comment: Off-topic: [Package `subfigure`](https://ctan.org/pkg/subfigure) is deprecated for a long time and therefore also not the best idea. See the link for more information and alternatives.